# Workflow designer line onclick too thin

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm making a workflowdesigner to create workflows on a canvas with wpf and vb.net. I have made it possible to draw lines(relations) between objects with a nice function. Now I want to implement a way to delete a relation. I add a onclick handler on the shape but the line is very thin and hard to click. I've heard to draw 2 lines 1 with a thicker stroke thickness, but this isn't possible since the drawline method is heavy on the cpu.

Thank you for helping

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a mouse down event handler to the Canvas, instead of the Shape objects, and then do [Hit Testing in the Visual Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx) (although the API is a bit strange) with a [hit test geometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometryhittestparameters.aspx), for example an ellipse. The Canvas needs to have its `Background` set (e.g. to `Transparent`) to receive mouse events.

Sorry that this is C#, but i don't speak VB:

```
private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Canvas canvas = sender as Canvas;
    EllipseGeometry hitTestGeometry =
        new EllipseGeometry(e.GetPosition(canvas), 10d, 10d);
    Shape hitShape = null;

    HitTestResultCallback hitTestCallback =
        result =>
        {
            hitShape = result.VisualHit as Shape;
            return hitShape != null ? HitTestResultBehavior.Stop : HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
        };

    VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(canvas, null, hitTestCallback, new GeometryHitTestParameters(hitTestGeometry));

    if (hitShape != null)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("hit shape: {0}", hitShape);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the equivalent VB code.  VB does not support multiline lambda expressions so the hit test callback has to be declared explicitly

```
Private Function htCallback(ByVal result As HitTestResult) _
 As HitTestResultBehavior
    Dim hitShape As Shape = Nothing
    hitShape = TryCast(result.VisualHit, Shape)
    If hitShape IsNot Nothing Then
        'do something 
    End If
    Return If(hitShape IsNot Nothing, HitTestResultBehavior.[Stop], _
      HitTestResultBehavior.[Continue])
End Function


Private Sub Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(ByVal sender As Object, _
  ByVal e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles Canvas1.MouseRightButtonDown
    Dim canvas As Canvas = TryCast(sender, Canvas)
    Dim hitTestGeometry As New EllipseGeometry(e.GetPosition(canvas), 10.0, 10.0)
    Dim hitTestCallback As HitTestResultCallback = _
      New HitTestResultCallback(AddressOf htCallback)
    VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(canvas, Nothing, hitTestCallback, _
      New GeometryHitTestParameters(hitTestGeometry))
End Sub
```

Comment: Does hit test have better performance than using the method described below?

Comment: @DavidVdd - with the hit test you can specify how large an area around the mouse you wish to look for the line (here it is a 10x10 ellipse) so you can have a larger tolerance area without making the line too much larger.  They are both fast/light operations, in any case, I don't think you should feel a performance hit from them.

Comment: @DavidVdd - what this doesn't do for you, however, is give you the highlight feedback like the other method.  You could put the hit test into the `MouseMove` event handler, however, and combine both ideas.  This would be continually performing hit tests while the mouse moves through the canvas, however, so this would add some amount of processing overhead.  Try it out and see is the best way, I would think.

Comment: @J... Thanks for the edit. I'll never grasp how you could voluntarily use that language :-)

Comment: @Clemens voluntarily is the keyword ;)  Worth noting that (I think) VB10 finally supports multiline lambdas - OP wasn't specific so this will work in any case.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a simple answer, but when you add your new line to the canvas you could do something like

```
AddHandler myLine.MouseEnter, AddressOf lineHover
AddHandler myLine.MouseLeave, AddressOf lineLeave
AddHandler myLine.MouseDown, AddressOf lineDelete
Canvas1.Children.Add(myLine)
```

where

```
Private Sub lineHover(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
    CType(sender, Line).StrokeThickness = 3
End Sub

Private Sub lineLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
    CType(sender, Line).StrokeThickness = 1
End Sub

Private Sub lineDelete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
    Canvas1.Children.Remove(CType(sender, Line))
End Sub
```

This way when your mouse hovers over a line its stroke thickness increases.  This makes the line much easier to click and also gives your users some nice feedback about which line they're deleting.